# Changing from md5 to sha256

Tags: php, authentication, hash

I'm trying to build a safe user authentication system.

The code is from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/simple-techniques-to-lock-down-your-website/

But Im trying to change from md5 to sha-256, But It wont login.

I just changed from

```
$auth_pass = md5( $row['salt'] . $password . $stat_salt );
```

to

```
$auth_pass = hash('sha256', $row['salt'] . $password . $stat_salt );
```

It does insert to db correctly but the login part wont work for some reason. Works with md5 but not sha256. Do u have to use sha256 in a diffrent way?

**Registration:**

```
// generate a unique salt
$salt = uniqid(mt_rand());

// combine them all together and hash them
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $password . $stat_salt );

// insert the values into the database
$register_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$hash."', '".$salt."')") or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
```

**Login**

```
// grab the row associated with the username from the form
$grab_row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'") or die ("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());

// if only one row was retrieved
if (mysql_num_rows($grab_row) == 1) {

// create an array from the row fields
$row = mysql_fetch_array($grab_row);

// re-hash the combined variables
$auth_pass = hash('sha256', $row['salt'] . $password . $stat_salt );

// check the database again for the row associated with the username and the rehashed password
$checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$auth_pass."'") or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());

// if only one row is retrieved output success or failure to the user
if (mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1) {
echo "<h1>Yippie, we are authenticated!</h1>";
} else {
echo '<h1>Oh no, we are not authenticated!</h1>';
}
} else {
echo '<h1>Oh no, we are not in the database!</h1>';
}
}
```

Comment: Oh, and you don’t need the database query. Just compare the return value of your `hash` call with the value in `$row['password']`.

Comment: stat_salt is a salt i have for all users

Comment: @Włodzimierz: I wouldn’t do that. One unique salt for each user is enough noise for the hashing. And loosing the global salt will make all of your hashes useless.

Comment: your saying >hash('sha256', $salt . $password )< is enough?

Comment: @Włodzimierz: Yes, that will suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It does insert to db correctly but [...]

how do you test it? `md5` returns 32-digit string, `hash('sha256', ...)` return 64-digit string. Is your `password` field long enough to accommodate it? if it's not, on insert `$hash` will be clipped to the length of the field, and comparison on select will fail.

Comment: Even if it were not, shouldn't the clipped SHA result be the same?

Comment: what clipped sha results have to do with it? OP's comparing `varchar`s

Comment: that was the problem my password field was 32 varchar

thank you so muich!